# Code works in debugging mode

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to upload some files and adding it to the drop down using one button.
It uploads the files and add it to the drop down when in debugging ( by adding breakpoints )but does not add it to the drop down otherwise.
Where am I going wrong.

Comment: why did you edit the question to remove the code? This version of your question, without the code block, is not answerable.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look it looks like you missed some quotes in your option tag's "value" attribute.

Try this:

```
$("#afterId").append("<option value='"+files[i].name+"'>"+files[i].name+"</option>");
```

Comment: no the problem is not the quotes. the code works when I open the debugger and run one step at a time.